# What does the 7 stand for in 7-Zip (.7z )?

Tags: 7-zip

Is there any significance the number 7 in 7-Zip?  I know it corresponds to the formating of the compression method and all of it's implied features, but what does the 7 mean?

Answer (score 3):

It is not mentioned in the [FAQ](http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html), the [changelog](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt), the [Wikipedia entry for 7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip), the [Wikipedia entry for 7z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z), or even in a [Dr. Dobb's interview](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/184405338).

You will have to ask [Igor Pavlov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_Pavlov_%28programmer%29) why he chose that name. Try the [SourceForge forum for 7-zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenmax/forums/forum/399008) or [Igor's SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/users/ipavlov/).